# What are the best Single Board Computers and their uses?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm just wondering what the best SBCs are for different categories. Eg: Networking, home media, automation etc.

Comment: Look at Raspberry. They have large community

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to hardware recommendations. It may be on-topic on the Hardware Recommendations SE. Check what is on-topic there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a list of the more relevant boards (for me) of the many we considered in the last months.

Raspberry PI 2

- 900MHz quad-core ARM Cortex-A7 CPU
- 1GB RAM
- 100 Mbps Ports
- Video decoding in hardware
- no SATA ports

Lamobo R1

http://linux-sunxi.org/Lamobo_R1 [80 USD]

- dual core A20
- 1GB RAM
- 5 Gigabit ethernet ports
- SATA port
- realtek wifi buggy

Banana Pro

http://hardware-libre.fr/2015/01/hands-on-the-new-banana-pro/

- dual core A20
- 1GB RAM
- gigabit ethernet and wifi
- SATA port

Orange PI

- weak, cheap H3 board
- SATA via USB (H3 SoC does not support SATA)

As for the 64 bit newcomers:

Pine 64

https://www.pine64.com

Cheap and slow board, no open source specialists backing up the project.

- 1.2 Ghz Quad-Core ARM Cortex A53 64-Bit Processor
- up to 2GB RAM

Odroid C2

http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/12/28/odroid-c2-amlogic-s905-development-board-is-in-the-works/

- S905 processor
- up to 2GB RAM

For more boards [Ringing in 2016 with 64 open-spec, hacker friendly SBCs](http://linuxgizmos.com/ringing-in-2016-with-64-open-spec-hacker-friendly-sbcs/)

Comment: I was saying I would add up later to the message, seen already the closing messages...my fault too. While it relates to Linux, this is indeed off-topic here.

Comment: (no use giving points here, as soons as this thread is deleted, they will be deducted. You might as well speed up the process and delete it yourself)

Comment: There are more nuances to this, like for instance xulong from Orange PIs not supporting models over time...complicated.